# K8S traffic from external reaching deleted pod

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, routes

I have 2 pods with simple echo app that are registered to the service that expose ELB in AWS.
I'm starting curl in a loop from my laptop to hit echo app and then I do `kubectl delete pod echo-xyz`
Results are wired as for next couple of seconds traffic is still being routed to deleted pod. Pod has been removed from endpoint list correctly though. The same test but issuing curl from inside a cluster to bypass ELB is working as expected - the moment i delete pod, traffic is being routed to single pod remaining until new one is created.
In the attached picture you can see on the left the test from inside a cluster and on the right from external via ELB.

[curl comparsion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7nWl.png)

K8s 1.16.8 installed via kops on AWS.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Comment: what is you exact ask in the question ? if you want to delete the pod immediately then do `kubectl delete pod echo-xyz --force --grace-period=0` .

Comment: Question is: 
Why after issuing a command kubectl delete pod-xyz any new traffic arriving to the cluster is still being redirected to the deleted pod? Pod should be removed from endpoint lists, all the iptables rules should be refreshed and no traffic should arrive there giving a pod chance to gracefully shutdown all the existing connections.

Comment: Are you using LoadBalancer type service? Pod should be removed from the list of endpoints as soon as the termination grace period begins

Comment: I'm - pod gets removed from endpoint list but still getting traffic for few seconds. I'm pretty sure that it's something related to ELB and how it keeps established sessions, but not sure yet how to explain it

Comment: i think that would be it:
https://www.cloudavail.com/blog/2014/01/27/aws-elb-pre-open-connection-expose-part-2

Answer (score 0):

The deletion of pods are not immediate. There are lists of events performed(wait for the grace period, preStop hooks, etc) by kubelet to bring down the pod once disruptions happen. Docs here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/

This process of graceful termination is by design that Kubernetes does not send `KILL` command, instead works with `TERM`(termination) signal.

Refer docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination

Also, `--force` delete is not suggested as it updates the API server without waiting for the resource to be deleted.

Comment: It's not about gracefull shutdown - this is different topic how application handles it. The bottom line is that one you do kubectl delete on pod, any new traffic shouldn't be redirected to this pod any more as pod is getting removed from endpoint lists. And this works fine when i test it from different pod in the cluster. Same tests from outside shows that traffic is still getting to the pod that has been deleted and is performing gracefull shutdown/preStop etc.